# php arrays and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out here ... im kinda stuck

```
functions.php
--------------
class stats{
public function Updates() 
{
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT blah blah ") or die(mysql_error());
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
     $data[]=$row;

   if(!empty($data))
   {
     return $data;
   }        
}
--------------
div_load.php
--------------
include_once('functions.php');
$son = new stats();
$updatesarray=$son->Updates();

if($updatesarray)
{
  foreach($updatesarray as $data)
  {
    $name=data['name'];

<div >blah blah</div>
  }
}
-----------
index.php
-----------
```

im trying to get new content using jquery load function.... rather than a page refresh every time ... it works with page refresh .. but i cannot get it to work with jquery load function .... could use the help .. thank you

Comment: What code are you using in your html page with the jQuery load function?

Comment: What's not working? Any errors? More detail is needed.

Comment: might be better to retun json format in your PHP and have jQuery parse that in the AJAX call

Comment: First of all, do you know how AJAX basically works? There is nothing in that code that supports or indicates AJAX. Are you stuck at the very beginning? It's hard to tell what exactly you need unless you specify precisely what the problem is. If you don't know AJAX, that's fine, just say so. :) - Second, what is the purpose of $name and when do you echo it to the browser? - Third, what's "<div >blah blah</div>" doing in the middle of the PHP code? That will result in a parse error. - Fourth, what's in index.php?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are instantiating a function here, but you should just call the function, you should only instantiate classes...

```
$son = new updates();
$updatesarray=$son->Updates();
```

You should be able to just call `$son = Updates();`
also, is the Updates function wrapped in a class called updates?  If not that code would error out... and you are not showing us the jquery or html code either, which is needed to answer the question.

Comment: Presumably it's in a class that he only copied the relevant function from.

Answer (score 0):

index.php just contains include(div-load.php)

As for jquery part im doing $(selector).live(click, function(){ this.load()});